# Finishing the current activity after the user clicks on notitifcation

Tags: android, notifications

In my android client program, when ever the user has updates a notification is received. When the user clicks on the notification, he is taken to a new activity where the notifications are displayed. Now the problem is while the user is viewing the updates if another notification is received and if he clicks on that notification a new activity is not being created. 
 The previous activity is displayed. the activity is not getting refreshed.<
I suspect this is because the current activity is not finished. How should I overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you try onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) in your code. What is happening in your case is the Activity Window is already in focussed state So nothing will happen when you click the notification bar and move to the same activity window. 
onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) will get executed each time you enter into that activity. So put your entire code into this. Even when the activity is called for first time,It will get executed. So copy ur code from  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) to

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
    {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
       setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);

           //Your code to be executed here
    }
```

And yea you need to have Oncreate() function also so you declare that as

```
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   }
```

Try this. **I hope it works for you**

Answer (score 0):

put this in the activity code in your manifest (can play with the parameter to fit better to your app).

> android:launchMode="singleTop"

Comment: make only one instance of your activity and if you already have an instance of that activity - it gets resumed

Comment: :That is exactly what I don't want. I want that if a the instance is already there, it should be finished and a new activity be started.

Comment: you should update the content by yourself when you recieve an intent from the notifications instead of finish one activity and create another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this attribute on your activity tag on the manifest :

```
android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |
                    "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
```

with value `singleTop`, it will not create an other activity but call the onNewIntent method of a potential Activity if exists.

[Activity Element Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finishing the current activity why should you use the onResume() method to update the ui with new notification data. Write the method to update the ui components and call it from onResume().

Comment: Will my current activity be paused when I click on the notification or just before that.

Comment: When you click on notification the current activity is getting paused.And started the activity another instance. So onResume() is called again. May i know are you using any flag for start new activity from notification. Better to use intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); flag before starting activity.